# How to prevent GhostScript from rastering the font when converting PDF or EPS to EPS?

Tags: ghostscript

I want to convert PDF or EPS to EPS using the following commands, respectively.

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=output.eps input.pdf
```

or

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=output.eps input.eps
```

How to prevent GhostScript from rastering the font when converting PDF or EPS to EPS?

Comment: Use `pdftops` instead, and you won't have this problem (also the resulting eps will be much smaller, and will have proper text in it (so you can search for and copy the text)).

Comment: @Lev: Can `pdftops` convert EPS to EPS?

Comment: You don't need any tool to leave the format of a file unchanged :-) Why do you want to convert eps to eps?

Comment: `dvips -E -o input.dvi` does not produce EPS with `%%HiResBoundingBox` header. So converting EPS to EPS will add the header.

Comment: If you only want to update the bbox then use epstool: `epstool --copy --bbox input.eps output.eps` will do nothing to the eps except update `%%BoundingBox` and `%%HiResBoundingBox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `-dNOCACHE` option. It is originally used for debugging, due to document of GS. But this is the only way I know.

Comment: `-dNOCACHE` is considered a debugging option because it turns the text glyphs into the set of outline curves that represents them, making for a *huge* file that is slow to render and you can no longer search for the text or copy/paste it.

Comment: Althouth it's worth pointing out that -dNOCACHE still vectorizes the text...