# How to remove PSTricks dictionary or library codes in an EPS file produced by dvips?

Tags: pstricks, eps

I have 2 mutually-exclusive methods to produce cropped PSTricks graphics in EPS format:

1. Using `latex input.tex` followed by `dvips input.dvi -E -o output.eps`.
2. Or using `latex input.tex` followed by `dvips input.dvi` followed by `ps2pdf input.ps` followed by `pdfcrop --hires input.pdf` followed by `pdftops -eps input-crop.pdf`.

For the sake of illustration, I chose the following code snippet as an input file.

```
% gridon.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](3,3)
\pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\rput[tr](3,3){3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### First Methode

I noticed the size of EPS files produced by the first method will be 4 times larger than ones produced by the second method.

I opened the EPS produced by the first method and the contents look like below:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%BoundingBox: 85 626 184 729
%%HiResBoundingBox: 85.272 626.784 183.390 728.016
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: gridon.dvi
%%CreationDate: Wed Jul 06 22:32:55 2011
%%DocumentFonts: CMR10
%%EndComments
%DVIPSWebPage: (www.radicaleye.com)
%DVIPSCommandLine: dvips gridon -E* -o gridon-crop.eps
%DVIPSParameters: dpi=600
%DVIPSSource:  TeX output 2011.07.06:2232
%%BeginProcSet: tex.pro 0 0
%!
/TeXDict 300 dict def TeXDict begin/N{def}def/B{bind def}N/S{exch}N/X{S
N}B/A{dup}B/TR{translate}N/isls false N/vsize 11 72 mul N/hsize 8.5 72
mul N/landplus90{false}def/@rigin{isls{[0 landplus90{1 -1}{-1 1}ifelse 0
0 0]concat}if 72 Resolution div 72 VResolution div neg scale isls{
landplus90{VResolution 72 div vsize mul 0 exch}{Resolution -72 div hsize
mul 0}ifelse TR}if Resolution VResolution vsize -72 div 1 add mul TR[
matrix currentmatrix{A A round sub abs 0.00001 lt{round}if}forall round
exch round exch]setmatrix}N/@landscape{/isls true N}B/@manualfeed{
statusdict/manualfeed true put}B/@copies{/#copies X}B/FMat[1 0 0 -1 0 0]
N/FBB[0 0 0 0]N/nn 0 N/IEn 0 N/ctr 0 N/df-tail{/nn 8 dict N nn begin
/FontType 3 N/FontMatrix fntrx N/FontBBox FBB N string/base X array
/BitMaps X/BuildChar{CharBuilder}N/Encoding IEn N end A{/foo setfont}2
array copy cvx N load 0 nn put/ctr 0 N[}B/sf 0 N/df{/sf 1 N/fntrx FMat N
df-tail}B/dfs{div/sf X/fntrx[sf 0 0 sf neg 0 0]N df-tail}B/E{pop nn A
definefont setfont}B/Cw{Cd A length 5 sub get}B/Ch{Cd A length 4 sub get
}B/Cx{128 Cd A length 3 sub get sub}B/Cy{Cd A length 2 sub get 127 sub}
B/Cdx{Cd A length 1 sub get}B/Ci{Cd A type/stringtype ne{ctr get/ctr ctr
1 add N}if}B/CharBuilder{save 3 1 roll S A/base get 2 index get S
/BitMaps get S get/Cd X pop/ctr 0 N Cdx 0 Cx Cy Ch sub Cx Cw add Cy
setcachedevice Cw Ch true[1 0 0 -1 -.1 Cx sub Cy .1 sub]{Ci}imagemask
restore}B/D{/cc X A type/stringtype ne{]}if nn/base get cc ctr put nn
/BitMaps get S ctr S sf 1 ne{A A length 1 sub A 2 index S get sf div put
}if put/ctr ctr 1 add N}B/I{cc 1 add D}B/bop{userdict/bop-hook known{
bop-hook}if/SI save N @rigin 0 0 moveto/V matrix currentmatrix A 1 get A
mul exch 0 get A mul add .99 lt{/QV}{/RV}ifelse load def pop pop}N/eop{
SI restore userdict/eop-hook known{eop-hook}if showpage}N/@start{
userdict/start-hook known{start-hook}if pop/VResolution X/Resolution X
1000 div/DVImag X/IEn 256 array N 2 string 0 1 255{IEn S A 360 add 36 4
index cvrs cvn put}for pop 65781.76 div/vsize X 65781.76 div/hsize X}N
/dir 0 def/dyy{/dir 0 def}B/dyt{/dir 1 def}B/dty{/dir 2 def}B/dtt{/dir 3
def}B/p{dir 2 eq{-90 rotate show 90 rotate}{dir 3 eq{-90 rotate show 90
rotate}{show}ifelse}ifelse}N/RMat[1 0 0 -1 0 0]N/BDot 260 string N/Rx 0
N/Ry 0 N/V{}B/RV/v{/Ry X/Rx X V}B statusdict begin/product where{pop
false[(Display)(NeXT)(LaserWriter 16/600)]{A length product length le{A
length product exch 0 exch getinterval eq{pop true exit}if}{pop}ifelse}
forall}{false}ifelse end{{gsave TR -.1 .1 TR 1 1 scale Rx Ry false RMat{
BDot}imagemask grestore}}{{gsave TR -.1 .1 TR Rx Ry scale 1 1 false RMat
{BDot}imagemask grestore}}ifelse B/QV{gsave newpath transform round exch
round exch itransform moveto Rx 0 rlineto 0 Ry neg rlineto Rx neg 0
rlineto fill grestore}B/a{moveto}B/delta 0 N/tail{A/delta X 0 rmoveto}B
/M{S p delta add tail}B/b{S p tail}B/c{-4 M}B/d{-3 M}B/e{-2 M}B/f{-1 M}
B/g{0 M}B/h{1 M}B/i{2 M}B/j{3 M}B/k{4 M}B/w{0 rmoveto}B/l{p -4 w}B/m{p
-3 w}B/n{p -2 w}B/o{p -1 w}B/q{p 1 w}B/r{p 2 w}B/s{p 3 w}B/t{p 4 w}B/x{
0 S rmoveto}B/y{3 2 roll p a}B/bos{/SS save N}B/eos{SS restore}B end

%%EndProcSet
%%BeginProcSet: pstricks.pro 0 0
% $Id: pstricks.pro 455 2011-01-30 11:19:19Z herbert $
%
%% PostScript prologue for pstricks.tex.
%% Version 1.07, 2009/04/30
%%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN archives
%% in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
%
%
% Define the follwing gs-functions if not known, eg when using distiller
%
systemdict /.setopacityalpha known not {/.setopacityalpha { pop } def } if
systemdict /.setblendmode known not {/.setblendmode { pop } def } if
systemdict /.setshapealpha known not {/.setshapealpha { pop } def } if
%
/tx@Dict 200 dict def               % the main PSTricks dictionary
tx@Dict begin
/ADict 25 dict def              % The arrow dictionaray
/CM { matrix currentmatrix } bind def
/SLW /setlinewidth load def
/CLW /currentlinewidth load def
/CP /currentpoint load def
/ED { exch def } bind def
/L /lineto load def
/T /translate load def
/TMatrix { } def
/RAngle { 0 } def
/Sqrt { dup 0 lt { pop 0 } { sqrt } ifelse } def  % return 0 for negative arguments 
/Atan { /atan load stopped { pop pop 0 } if } def % return 0 if atan not known
/ATAN1 {neg -1 atan 180 sub } def       % atan(x) (only one parameter)
/Div { dup 0 eq { pop } { div } ifelse } def    % control the division
/tan { dup cos abs 1.e-10 lt 
  { pop 1.e10 }                 % return 1.e10 as infinit
  { dup sin exch cos div } ifelse       % default sin/cos
} def
/Tan { dup sin exch cos Div } def       % sin(x)/cos(x) x in degrees
/Acos {dup dup mul neg 1 add dup 0 lt {     % arc cos, returns 0 when negative root
  pop pop 0 }{ sqrt exch atan} ifelse } def
/NET { neg exch neg exch T } def            % change coordinate system to the negative one      
/Pyth { dup mul exch dup mul add sqrt } def     % Pythagoras, expects 2 parameter
/Pyth2 {                    % Pythagoras, xA yA xB yB
  3 -1 roll         % xA xB yB yA
  sub           % xA xB yB-yA
  3 1 roll      % yB-yA xA xB
  sub           % yB-yA xA-xB
  Pyth } def
/PtoC { 2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul } def   % Polar to Cartesian
/Rand { rand 4294967295 div } def       % a real random number
%----------------- hv added 20050516 ---------------
/PiDiv2 1.57079632680 def
/Pi 3.14159265359 def 
/TwoPi 6.28318530718 def
/Euler 2.71828182846 def 
%/e Euler bind def
%
/RadtoDeg { 180 mul Pi div } bind def       % convert from radian to degrees
/DegtoRad { Pi mul 180 div } bind def       % viceversa
%----------------- hv end---------------------------
/PathLength@ { /z z y y1 sub x x1 sub Pyth add def /y1 y def /x1 x def } def
%
/PathLength { 
  flattenpath /z 0 def 
  { /y1 ED /x1 ED /y2 y1 def /x2 x1 def }
  { /y ED /x ED PathLength@ } 
  {} 
  { /y y2 def /x x2 def PathLength@ }
  /pathforall load stopped { pop pop pop pop } if 
  z 
} def
%
/STP { .996264 dup scale } def          % BP/PT scaling
/STV { SDict begin normalscale end STP  } def   % 
%
/DashLine {
    dup 0 gt
    { /a .5 def PathLength exch div }
    { pop /a 1 def PathLength } ifelse
    /b ED % pattern should fit evenly in b
    dup /X ED % pattern array
    0 get /y ED % length of first black segment
    /z 0 X {add} forall def % length of the full pattern
    %% Computation of the scaling factor as described by van Zandt:
    b a .5 sub 2 mul y mul sub z Div round
    z mul a .5 sub 2 mul y mul add b exch Div
    %%%% scaling factor on stack.
    /z ED %% now, z is the scaling factor
    false % for the length test below
    X { z mul } forall X astore %% modification TN 04-08-07
    %%% Checking whether at least one dash in X has positive length:
    {0 gt or} forall
    { X 1 a sub y mul }
    { [ 1 0 ] 0 }
    ifelse
    setdash stroke
} def
%
/DotLine { 
  /b PathLength def 
  /a ED /z ED /y CLW def 
  /z y z add def 
  a 0 gt { 
    /b b a div def 
  }{ 
    a 0 eq { 
      /b b y sub def 
    }{ a -3 eq { 
      /b b y add def } if 
    } ifelse 
  } ifelse 
  [ 0 b b z Div round Div dup 0 le { pop 1 } if ] 
  a 0 gt { 0 }{ y 2 div a -2 gt { neg }if } ifelse 
  setdash 1 setlinecap stroke 
} def
%
/SymbolLine {   % on stack [ x y x y ...
  counttomark                   % number of elements
  2 div cvi /n ED                   % n pairs
  /YA ED /XA ED                 % the start point
  n 1 sub { 
    /YB ED /XB ED
    /XLength XB XA sub def
    /YLength YB YA sub def
    /PAngle YLength XLength Atan def
    /XYLength XLength YLength Pyth def
    /nSym XYLength SymStep div cvi def
    /Shift Symbol stringwidth pop 2 div def 
    /deltaX XLength nSym div def
    /deltaY YLength nSym div def
    XA Shift sub YA Shift sub moveto 
    nSym { 
      gsave rotateSymbol { PAngle 180 sub CorrAngle sub rotate } if
      Symbol show 
      grestore 
      deltaX deltaY rmoveto
    } repeat
    /YA YB def /XA XB def
  } repeat 
  XA Shift sub YA Shift sub moveto 
  gsave rotateSymbol { PAngle 180 sub CorrAngle sub rotate } if
  Symbol show grestore
  pop               % delete the mark symbol
} def
%
/LineFill { % hv ------------ patch 7 -------------
  gsave 
  abs /hatchWidthInc ED
  abs /hatchSepInc ED
  abs CLW add /a ED 
  a 0 dtransform round exch round exch
  2 copy idtransform 
  exch Atan rotate 
  idtransform pop /a ED 
  .25 .25 itransform pathbbox 
  /y2 ED 
  a Div ceiling cvi /x2 ED /y1 ED 
  a Div cvi /x1 ED /y2 y2 y1 sub def 
  clip 
  newpath 
  2 setlinecap 
  systemdict
  /setstrokeadjust known { true setstrokeadjust } if 
  x2 x1 sub 1 add { 
    x1 a mul y1 moveto 0 y2 rlineto stroke 
    /x1 x1 1 add 
      hatchWidthInc 0 gt { CLW add } if 
    def 
    hatchSepInc 0 gt hatchWidthInc 0 gt or { 
      /a a hatchSepInc add def
      CLW hatchWidthInc add SLW 
    } if
  } repeat 
  grestore 
  pop pop } def
%
/PenroseFill {%  on stack: scaling factor
  dup dup scale
  1 exch div round /penroseFactor ED 
  a 0 dtransform round exch round exch
  2 copy idtransform 
  exch Atan rotate 
  idtransform pop /a ED 
  .25 .25 itransform pathbbox 
  /y2 ED 
  a Div ceiling cvi /x2 ED /y1 ED 
  a Div cvi /x1 ED /y2 y2 y1 sub def 
  clip 
  newpath 
  systemdict
  /setstrokeadjust known { true setstrokeadjust } if 
  /I/S/L/W/G/+/Z/F/E/D[/def/exch/for{E D}/add{s E get mul}
 { Z -36.2001 1 33 }{25 E S rlineto}{/q Z dup q G E q 1 + G}{Z 2 2}]{cvx def}forall
  [0 72 1008 {dup sin E cos }F ]1 setlinejoin/s W{/a W{/b I 10{/i I 4{/m I moveto
  i m +/j I 10{/l Z b m l + G a l G sub s m get div .2 + floor .3 + 25
  mul j l + S rmoveto}F i L j L stroke }F}F}F}F 
  grestore 
  pop pop 
} def
%
/TruchetFill { %     on stack: scaling factor
  10 dict begin
  dup dup scale
  1 exch div round /penroseFactor ED 
  a 0 dtransform round exch round exch
  2 copy idtransform 
  exch Atan rotate 
  idtransform pop /a ED 
  .25 .25 itransform pathbbox 
  /y2 ED 
  a Div ceiling cvi /x2 ED /y1 ED 
  a Div cvi /x1 ED /y2 y2 y1 sub def 
  clip 
  newpath 
  systemdict
  /setstrokeadjust known { true setstrokeadjust } if 
  /ma a neg def
  /ha a 2 div def 
  /mha ha neg def
  /tile { 
    rand dup 2 idiv 2 mul eq { 90 rotate } if
    mha mha moveto ha mha lineto
    ha ha lineto mha ha lineto
%    closepath .1 setlinewidth stroke
    contents
  } def
  /contents{ 
    0 ha moveto ha 0 lineto
    0 mha moveto mha 0 lineto
%    1 setlinewidth stroke
  } def
  /dotiling {
    f ma mul a f a mul { 
      /i exch def
      f ma mul a f a mul { 
        /j exch def
        gsave i j translate
        tile stroke grestore
      } for
    } for
  } def
%
  /f 3 def 
  5 srand dotiling 
  end % local user dict
} def
%
/BeginArrow { 
  ADict begin           % hold it local, for end see EndArrow
  /@mtrx CM def 
  gsave 
  2 copy T 
  2 index sub neg exch 
  3 index sub exch Atan 
  rotate newpath 
} def
%
/EndArrow { @mtrx setmatrix CP grestore end } def % end the ADict
%
/Arrow { 
  CLW mul add dup 
  2 div /w ED 
  mul dup /h ED 
  mul /a ED 
  { 0 h T 1 -1 scale } if 
  w neg h moveto 
  0 0 L w h L w neg a neg rlineto 
  gsave fill grestore 
} def
%
/ArrowD { % the sides are drawn as curves (hv 20071211)
  CLW mul add dup 
  2 div /w ED 
  mul dup /h ED 
  mul /Inset ED 
  { 0 h T 1 -1 scale } if % changes the direction
% we use y=w/h^2 * x^2 as equation for the control points
% for the coordinates the arrow is seen from top to bottom
% the bottom (tip) is (0;0)
  w neg h moveto % lower left of >
  w 9 div 4 mul neg h 3 div 2 mul
  w 9 div neg       h 3 div  
  0 0 curveto    % tip of >
  w 9 div        h 3 div  
  w 9 div 4 mul  h 3 div 2 mul
  w h curveto % upper left of >
  w neg Inset neg rlineto % move to x=0 and inset
  gsave fill grestore 
} def 
%
/Tbar { 
  CLW mul add /z ED 
  z -2 div CLW 2 div moveto 
  z 0 rlineto stroke 
  0 CLW moveto 
} def
%
/Bracket { 
  CLW mul add dup CLW sub 2 div 
  /x ED mul CLW add /y ED /z CLW 2 div def 
  x neg y moveto 
  x neg CLW 2 div L x CLW 2 div L x y L stroke 
  0 CLW moveto 
} def
%
/RoundBracket { 
  CLW mul add dup 2 div 
  /x ED mul /y ED /mtrx CM def 
  0 CLW 2 div T x y mul 0 ne { x y scale } if 
  1 1 moveto 
  .85 .5 .35 0 0 0 curveto 
  -.35 0 -.85 .5 -1 1 curveto 
  mtrx setmatrix stroke 0 CLW moveto 
} def
%
/SD { 0 360 arc fill } def
%
/EndDot { % DS is the dot size 
  { /z DS def } { /z 0 def } ifelse     % outer or inner dimen 
  /b ED                 % the color definition
  0 z DS SD 
  b { 0 z DS CLW sub SD } if 
  0 DS z add CLW 4 div sub 
  moveto 
} def
%
/Shadow { [ { /moveto load } { /lineto load } { /curveto load } {
  /closepath load } /pathforall load stopped { pop pop pop pop CP /moveto
  load } if ] cvx newpath 3 1 roll T exec } def
%
/NArray { % holds the coordinates and on top of stack the showpoints boolean
  /showpoints ED 
  counttomark 2 div dup cvi /n ED   % n 2 div on stack 
  n eq not { exch pop } if      % even numbers of points? delete one
  showpoints 
    { ] aload /Points ED } 
    { n 2 mul 1 add -1 roll pop } ifelse    % delete the mark symbol 
} def
%
/Line { 
  NArray n 0 eq not 
    { n 1 eq { 0 0 /n 2 def } if ArrowA /n n 2 sub def 
      n { Lineto } repeat 
      CP 4 2 roll ArrowB L pop pop 
    } if 
} def
%
/LineToYAxis {
  NArray            % all x-y pairs on stack
  n { 2 copy moveto % go to current point
    0 exch Lineto   % line to y-axis
    pop             % delete old x-value
  } repeat
} def
%
/LineToXAxis{
  NArray        % all x-y pairs on stack
  n 0 eq not
    { n 1 eq { 0 0 /n 2 def } if
      ArrowA
      /n n 2 sub def
      CP 2 copy moveto pop 0 Lineto
      n { 2 copy moveto pop 0 Lineto } repeat
      CP
      4 2 roll
      ArrowB
      2 copy moveto pop 0
      L
      pop pop } if
} def
%
/Arcto { 
  /a [ 6 -2 roll ] cvx def 
  a r 
  /arcto load stopped { 5 } { 4 } ifelse { pop } repeat 
  a 
} def
%
/CheckClosed { 
  dup n 2 mul 1 sub index eq 2 index n 2 mul 1 add index eq
  and { pop pop /n n 1 sub def } if 
} def
%
/Polygon { 
  NArray n 2 eq { 0 0 /n 3 def } if 
  n 3 lt 
    { n { pop pop } repeat } 
    { n 3 gt { CheckClosed } if 
      n 2 mul -2 roll 
      /y0 ED /x0 ED /y1 ED /x1 ED  
      x1 y1 
      /x1 x0 x1 add 2 div def 
      /y1 y0 y1 add 2 div def 
      x1 y1 moveto 
      /n n 2 sub def 
      n { Lineto } repeat 
      x1 y1 x0 y0 6 4 roll Lineto
      Lineto pop pop closepath } ifelse 
} def
%
/SymbolPolygon {   % on stack [ x y x y ...
  counttomark                   % number of elements
  2 add /m ED
  2 copy m 2 roll               % copy last two
  m 2 div cvi /n ED                 % n pairs
  /YA ED /XA ED                 % the start point
  n 1 sub { 
    /YB ED /XB ED
    /XLength XB XA sub def
    /YLength YB YA sub def
    /PAngle YLength XLength Atan def
    /XYLength XLength YLength Pyth def
    /nSym XYLength SymStep Div cvi def
    /Shift Symbol stringwidth pop 2 Div def 
    /deltaX XLength nSym Div def
    /deltaY YLength nSym Div def
    XA Shift sub YA Shift sub moveto 
    nSym { 
      gsave rotateSymbol { PAngle 180 sub CorrAngle sub rotate } if
      Symbol show 
      grestore 
      deltaX deltaY rmoveto
    } repeat
%    XB Shift sub YB Shift sub moveto Symbol show
    /YA YB def /XA XB def
  } repeat 
  pop   % delete the mark symbol
} def
%
/Diamond { 
  /mtrx CM def 
  T rotate 
  /h ED 
  /w ED 
  dup 0 eq { pop } { CLW mul neg 
    /d ED 
    /a w h Atan def 
    /h d a sin Div h add def 
    /w d a cos Div w add def } ifelse 
  mark w 2 div h 2 div w 0 0 h neg w neg 0 0 h w 2 div h 2 div 
  /ArrowA { moveto } def 
  /ArrowB { } def 
  false Line 
  closepath mtrx setmatrix } def
%
/Triangle { 
  /mtrx CM def 
  translate 
  rotate /h ED 2 div /w ED 
  dup CLW mul /d ED 
  /h h d w h Atan sin Div sub def 
  /w w d h w Atan 2 div dup cos exch sin Div mul sub def 
  mark 
  0 d w neg d 0 h w d 0 d 
  /ArrowA { moveto } def 
  /ArrowB { } def 
  false 
  Line 
  closepath 
  mtrx
% DG/SR modification begin - Jun.  1, 1998 - Patch 3 (from Michael Vulis)
% setmatrix } def
  setmatrix pop 
} def
% DG/SR modification end
%
/CCA { 
  /y ED /x ED 
  2 copy y sub /dy1 ED 
  x sub /dx1 ED 
  /l1 dx1 dy1 Pyth def 
} def
%
/CC { 
  /l0 l1 def 
  /x1 x dx sub def 
  /y1 y dy sub def 
  /dx0 dx1 def 
  /dy0 dy1 def 
  CCA 
  /dx dx0 l1 c exp mul dx1 l0 c exp mul add def 
  /dy dy0 l1 c exp mul dy1 l0 c exp mul add def 
  /m dx0 dy0 Atan dx1 dy1 Atan sub 2 div cos abs b exp a mul dx dy Pyth Div 2 div def 
  /x2 x l0 dx mul m mul sub def
  /y2 y l0 dy mul m mul sub def 
  /dx l1 dx mul m mul neg def 
  /dy l1 dy mul m mul neg def 
} def
%
/IC { 
  /c c 1 add def 
  c 0 lt { /c 0 def } { c 3 gt { /c 3 def } if } ifelse 
  /a a 2 mul 3 div 45 cos b exp div def 
  CCA 
  /dx 0 def 
  /dy 0 def 
} def
%
/BOC { IC CC x2 y2 x1 y1 ArrowA CP 4 2 roll x y curveto } def
/NC { CC x1 y1 x2 y2 x y curveto } def
/EOC { x dx sub y dy sub 4 2 roll ArrowB 2 copy curveto } def
/BAC { IC CC x y moveto CC x1 y1 CP ArrowA } def
/NAC { x2 y2 x y curveto CC x1 y1 } def
/EAC { x2 y2 x y ArrowB curveto pop pop } def
%
/OpenCurve { 
  NArray n 3 lt 
    { n { pop pop } repeat } 
    { BOC /n n 3 sub def n { NC } repeat EOC } ifelse 
} def
%
/CurvePath { 
  flattenpath /z 0 def /z0 0 def
  { /y1 ED /x1 ED /y2 y1 def /x2 x1 def 
    x1 Shift sub y1 Shift sub moveto 
    gsave 
    startAngle rotate Symbol show 
    grestore /z0 z def }
  { /y ED /x ED PathLength@ z z0 sub SymStep ge {
      x Shift sub y Shift sub moveto 
      gsave 
      rotateSymbol { y yOld sub x xOld sub Atan 180 sub CorrAngle sub rotate } if
      Symbol show 
      grestore /z0 z def } if 
    /yOld y def /xOld x def } 
  {} 
  { /y y2 def /x x2 def PathLength@ 
    x Shift sub y Shift sub moveto 
    gsave
    rotateSymbol { y yOld sub x xOld sub Atan 180 sub CorrAngle sub rotate } if
    Symbol show 
    grestore
  }
  pathforall 
  z 
} def
%
/OpenSymbolCurve { 
  OpenCurve
  0.1 setflat
  /Shift Symbol stringwidth pop 2 div def 
  CurvePath 
} def
%
/AltCurve { 
  { false NArray n 2 mul 2 roll 
    [ n 2 mul 3 sub 1 roll ] aload
    /Points ED 
    n 2 mul -2 roll } 
  { false NArray } ifelse 
  n 4 lt { n { pop pop } repeat } { BAC /n n 4 sub def n { NAC } repeat EAC } ifelse 
} def
%
/AltOpenSymbolCurve { 
  AltCurve
  0.1 setflat
  /Shift Symbol stringwidth pop 2 div def 
  CurvePath 
} def


% ----------- the remaining codes are trimmed for simplicity ------------------
```

### Second Method

The second method produces more compact EPS as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
% Produced by xpdf/pdftops 3.02pl4
%%Creator: TeX
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 99 102
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 98.118 101.232
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: procset xpdf 3.02pl4 0
%%Copyright: Copyright 1996-2007 Glyph & Cog, LLC
/xpdf 75 dict def xpdf begin
% PDF special state
/pdfDictSize 15 def
/pdfSetup {
  3 1 roll 2 array astore
  /setpagedevice where {
    pop 3 dict begin
      /PageSize exch def
      /ImagingBBox null def
      /Policies 1 dict dup begin /PageSize 3 def end def
      { /Duplex true def } if
    currentdict end setpagedevice
  } {
    pop pop
  } ifelse
} def
/pdfStartPage {
  pdfDictSize dict begin
  /pdfFillCS [] def
  /pdfFillXform {} def
  /pdfStrokeCS [] def
  /pdfStrokeXform {} def
  /pdfFill [0] def
  /pdfStroke [0] def
  /pdfFillOP false def
  /pdfStrokeOP false def
  /pdfLastFill false def
  /pdfLastStroke false def
  /pdfTextMat [1 0 0 1 0 0] def
  /pdfFontSize 0 def
  /pdfCharSpacing 0 def
  /pdfTextRender 0 def
  /pdfTextRise 0 def
  /pdfWordSpacing 0 def
  /pdfHorizScaling 1 def
  /pdfTextClipPath [] def
} def
/pdfEndPage { end } def
% PDF color state
/cs { /pdfFillXform exch def dup /pdfFillCS exch def
      setcolorspace } def
/CS { /pdfStrokeXform exch def dup /pdfStrokeCS exch def
      setcolorspace } def
/sc { pdfLastFill not { pdfFillCS setcolorspace } if
      dup /pdfFill exch def aload pop pdfFillXform setcolor
     /pdfLastFill true def /pdfLastStroke false def } def
/SC { pdfLastStroke not { pdfStrokeCS setcolorspace } if
      dup /pdfStroke exch def aload pop pdfStrokeXform setcolor
     /pdfLastStroke true def /pdfLastFill false def } def
/op { /pdfFillOP exch def
      pdfLastFill { pdfFillOP setoverprint } if } def
/OP { /pdfStrokeOP exch def
      pdfLastStroke { pdfStrokeOP setoverprint } if } def
/fCol {
  pdfLastFill not {
    pdfFillCS setcolorspace
    pdfFill aload pop pdfFillXform setcolor
    pdfFillOP setoverprint
    /pdfLastFill true def /pdfLastStroke false def
  } if
} def
/sCol {
  pdfLastStroke not {
    pdfStrokeCS setcolorspace
    pdfStroke aload pop pdfStrokeXform setcolor
    pdfStrokeOP setoverprint
    /pdfLastStroke true def /pdfLastFill false def
  } if
} def
% build a font
/pdfMakeFont {
  4 3 roll findfont
  4 2 roll matrix scale makefont
  dup length dict begin
    { 1 index /FID ne { def } { pop pop } ifelse } forall
    /Encoding exch def
    currentdict
  end
  definefont pop
} def
/pdfMakeFont16 {
  exch findfont
  dup length dict begin
    { 1 index /FID ne { def } { pop pop } ifelse } forall
    /WMode exch def
    currentdict
  end
  definefont pop
} def
% graphics state operators
/q { gsave pdfDictSize dict begin } def
/Q {
  end grestore
  /pdfLastFill where {
    pop
    pdfLastFill {
      pdfFillOP setoverprint
    } {
      pdfStrokeOP setoverprint
    } ifelse
  } if
} def
/cm { concat } def
/d { setdash } def
/i { setflat } def
/j { setlinejoin } def
/J { setlinecap } def
/M { setmiterlimit } def
/w { setlinewidth } def
% path segment operators
/m { moveto } def
/l { lineto } def
/c { curveto } def
/re { 4 2 roll moveto 1 index 0 rlineto 0 exch rlineto
      neg 0 rlineto closepath } def
/h { closepath } def
% path painting operators
/S { sCol stroke } def
/Sf { fCol stroke } def
/f { fCol fill } def
/f* { fCol eofill } def
% clipping operators
/W { clip newpath } def
/W* { eoclip newpath } def
/Ws { strokepath clip newpath } def
% text state operators
/Tc { /pdfCharSpacing exch def } def
/Tf { dup /pdfFontSize exch def
      dup pdfHorizScaling mul exch matrix scale
      pdfTextMat matrix concatmatrix dup 4 0 put dup 5 0 put
      exch findfont exch makefont setfont } def
/Tr { /pdfTextRender exch def } def
/Ts { /pdfTextRise exch def } def
/Tw { /pdfWordSpacing exch def } def
/Tz { /pdfHorizScaling exch def } def
% text positioning operators
/Td { pdfTextMat transform moveto } def
/Tm { /pdfTextMat exch def } def
% text string operators
/cshow where {
  pop
  /cshow2 {
    dup {
      pop pop
      1 string dup 0 3 index put 3 index exec
    } exch cshow
    pop pop
  } def
}{
  /cshow2 {
    currentfont /FontType get 0 eq {
      0 2 2 index length 1 sub {
        2 copy get exch 1 add 2 index exch get
        2 copy exch 256 mul add
        2 string dup 0 6 5 roll put dup 1 5 4 roll put
        3 index exec
      } for
    } {
      dup {
        1 string dup 0 3 index put 3 index exec
      } forall
    } ifelse
    pop pop
  } def
} ifelse
/awcp {
  exch {
    false charpath
    5 index 5 index rmoveto
    6 index eq { 7 index 7 index rmoveto } if
  } exch cshow2
  6 {pop} repeat
} def
/Tj {
  fCol
  1 index stringwidth pdfTextMat idtransform pop
  sub 1 index length dup 0 ne { div } { pop pop 0 } ifelse
  pdfWordSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul 0 pdfTextMat dtransform 32
  4 3 roll pdfCharSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul add 0
  pdfTextMat dtransform
  6 5 roll Tj1
} def
/Tj16 {
  fCol
  2 index stringwidth pdfTextMat idtransform pop
  sub exch div
  pdfWordSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul 0 pdfTextMat dtransform 32
  4 3 roll pdfCharSpacing pdfHorizScaling mul add 0
  pdfTextMat dtransform
  6 5 roll Tj1
} def
/Tj16V {
  fCol
  2 index stringwidth pdfTextMat idtransform exch pop
  sub exch div
  0 pdfWordSpacing pdfTextMat dtransform 32
  4 3 roll pdfCharSpacing add 0 exch
  pdfTextMat dtransform
  6 5 roll Tj1
} def
/Tj1 {
  0 pdfTextRise pdfTextMat dtransform rmoveto
  currentpoint 8 2 roll
  pdfTextRender 1 and 0 eq {
    6 copy awidthshow
  } if
  pdfTextRender 3 and dup 1 eq exch 2 eq or {
    7 index 7 index moveto
    6 copy
    currentfont /FontType get 3 eq { fCol } { sCol } ifelse
    false awcp currentpoint stroke moveto
  } if
  pdfTextRender 4 and 0 ne {
    8 6 roll moveto
    false awcp
    /pdfTextClipPath [ pdfTextClipPath aload pop
      {/moveto cvx}
      {/lineto cvx}
      {/curveto cvx}
      {/closepath cvx}
    pathforall ] def
    currentpoint newpath moveto
  } {
    8 {pop} repeat
  } ifelse
  0 pdfTextRise neg pdfTextMat dtransform rmoveto
} def
/TJm { pdfFontSize 0.001 mul mul neg 0
       pdfTextMat dtransform rmoveto } def
/TJmV { pdfFontSize 0.001 mul mul neg 0 exch
        pdfTextMat dtransform rmoveto } def
/Tclip { pdfTextClipPath cvx exec clip newpath
         /pdfTextClipPath [] def } def
% Level 2 image operators
/pdfImBuf 100 string def
/pdfIm {
  image
  { currentfile pdfImBuf readline
    not { pop exit } if
    (%-EOD-) eq { exit } if } loop
} def
/pdfImM {
  fCol imagemask
  { currentfile pdfImBuf readline
    not { pop exit } if
    (%-EOD-) eq { exit } if } loop
} def
/pr { 2 index 2 index 3 2 roll putinterval 4 add } def
/pdfImClip {
  gsave
  0 2 4 index length 1 sub {
    dup 4 index exch 2 copy
    get 5 index div put
    1 add 3 index exch 2 copy
    get 3 index div put
  } for
  pop pop rectclip
} def
/pdfImClipEnd { grestore } def


% ----------- the remaining codes are trimmed for simplicity ------------------
```

### Questions

I think the EPS in the first method contains unnecessary PSTricks codes, i.e., PSTricks dictionary and library codes. How to remove them?

Comment: `$Id: pstricks.pro 327 2010-05-24 15:54:43Z herbert $` looks like `pstricks` to me. Seems to be a set of general PhostScript macros. `Define the follwing gs-functions if not known, eg when using distiller` So they don't seem to be totally unnecessary. They are apparently there to make the (E)PS more compatible. Anyway, Herbert can tell you that.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, I think it is like a library that can be removed.

Comment: then try to remove it ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: Why must PSTricks library and dictionary codes be embedded in EPS for the first method?

Comment: in the 2nd case you are using ghostscript, which is a postscript interpreter. It runs the code and exports it into pdf, the reason why only needed functions are used and part of the pdf.

Comment: @Herbert: Is it possible to use GS to do the same thing for the first case?

Comment: @xport: see answer

Comment: @xport: `latex a.tex; dvips a.dvi; inkscape --export-eps a.eps a.ps` gives me a 94k `a.ps` and a 74k `a.eps`. Fonts look fine!

Comment: EPS of 74 k is still too big, we can actually obtain smaller one, i.e., 16 k using the method A in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22120/2099 the only issue is about the bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run:

```
dvips <file>
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=<file>.eps  -f <file>.ps
```

Comment: fonts get rasterized.

Comment: I was going to suggest `eps2eps` but it also uses Ghostscript internally (might just do the exact same thing) and apparently also rasters the font. Space difference: 94k -> 4k ! (@xport)

Comment: there is only one free PostScript interpreter and that is ghostscript.

Comment: I have made a question about the font rasterization here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22095/2099. I want to avoid it.

Comment: With `-dNOCACHE` option, we can avoid font rasterization but the font gets converted to a set of outlines curves that cannot be processed by text-based system. :-)

Comment: Actually outline curves produced by `-dNOCACHE` does not make a big issue because I don't need full text search feature in my book.

Comment: +1 and accepted but I add `-dNOCACHE` to make fonts a set of outline curves which are better than the rasterized fonts.

Comment: It does not work with transparent objects.