# Prerendering PostScript commands in EPS with GhostScript makes transparent objects opaque

Tags: eps, ghostscript, transparency

### Background

If the following PSTricks diagram

```
% Circle.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(-1,-1)(1,1)
\rput(0,0){$E\not=mc^2$}
\pscircle*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5]{1}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

is compiled with `MethodA.bat` below,

```
rem MethodA.bat takes an input file name without extension
latex %1
dvips -D10000 %1 -E -o %1-temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox %1-temp.eps %1.eps
```

I got a huge EPS output to which the raw PSTricks libraries are attached.

In [How to remove PSTricks dictionary or library codes in an EPS file produced by dvips?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22131), I asked this issue and Herbert suggested me to reprocess the resulting EPS with GhostScript in advance. I have tried it with `MethodB.bat` instead of `MethodA.bat` as follows.

```
rem MethodB.bat takes an input file name without extension
latex %1
dvips -D10000 %1 -E -o %1-temp.eps
gswin32c -r10000 -dNOCACHE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=%1.eps %1-temp.eps
```

### Issue & Question

I import the resulting EPS image from within the following main input file,

```
% Main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Circle}
\end{document}
```

which is compiled with `Batch.bat` as follows,

```
rem Batch.bat takes an input file name without extension.
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -D10000 -t unknown %1
ps2pdf -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps
```

The EPS produced by `MethodA.bat` preserves the transparency but the one produced by `MethodB.bat` does not. Thus invoking GhostScript in `MethodB.bat` is the source of problem, GhostScript seems to be unable to work with transparency. How to fix it?

Comment: Leave the pstricks library codes in. It only makes a difference of 100kB at most, and even this is disappears once you process the eps into pdf.

Comment: Loading `pst-barcode` takes 700kB. Unused packages should not be loaded as they will make bigger EPS files.

Comment: Pst-barcode is special, being significantly larger than other pstricks pacakges. It still doesn't matter since it all gets removed when you actually produce a pdf from the eps figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostScript in Level 2 doesn't know any kind of transparency, the reason why ghostscript uses its own commands only when it uses the pdfwrite device.

Comment: +1 How to promote my PSTricks diagram to a higher level such that it can be understood by GhostScript with `epswrite`?

Comment: I cannot see any senseful reason to use ghostscript for writing an eps file from a ps file. PostScript Level3 is _not_ available on nearly all printers

Comment: EPS produced by `dvips -E input.dvi -o output.eps` is too huge because it contains raw PSTricks libraries. Reprocessing the EPS to remove raw PSTricks libraries does make sense here.

Comment: we had this discussion more than hundred times ... space so no more a problem today.

Comment: level3 wouldn't help here anyway.

Comment: sure, then I do not need to define the transparency with ghostscript commands